# Suggest good books for Advanced Data Structure and Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, computational-geometry, books, backtracking

I don't really need hands on coding help, I need to clear my concepts of some of the more complex topics of DS and Algo like NP-Completeness, Computational Geometry, String Matching, Multithreaded Algorithms and Backtracking Algorithms. I have so far read CLRF(Cormen) as my go to book. But sometimes I just can't wrap my head around the more complex topics as mentioned above.

Comment: (Who is **F**?)

Comment: @greybeard surely Clissord Ftein, the demonic double of Clifford Stein.

Answer (score 1):

I find Algorithm Design by Kleinberg and Tardos an excellent resource. It will cover some of the topics you mentioned.